# Can not download in Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download File inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

I have a WebView on my screen:

```
webDownloadTicket = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewToDownload);
webDownloadTicket.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webDownloadTicket.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
      // and load url
webDownloadTicket.loadUrl("xxx.com/TicketWEB/download.jsp");
      // setup for download listener
webDownloadTicket.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

I was testing with browser, going to [this](http://example.com/TicketWEB/download.jsp) URL 
and then press the download button, it will download a JSON file.

But when I test on my Android app with that code, it can load the web page but can not download anything when I press download button.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @Gunna: my file need download is a *.json

Comment: @nandeesh: I dont understand what your mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common answer for not being able to access network from an app is a missing permission-declaration in AndroidManifest.xml. Check the file for this line and add it if it's not there:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I did it.
becuz I can go to link www.xxx.com/TicketWEB/download.jsp
In this page, have a button, and when I press it, download a file.
But i can not do in my app. 
when i test with browser on my phone, it ok.