# Android: Using Webview but no downloading

Tags: android, apk

I am using webview to open a website inside android app, but when clicking on download files link its not starting download. how i do it ???

The site is of music downlaod but when clicking on mp3 file link nothing happens.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
    // browser app does.
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final Activity activity = this;
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //This will load the webpage that we want to see
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.xtramasti.com/");



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() { ... });`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069265/1276374)

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDownloadListener(android.webkit.DownloadListener)):

> Registers the interface to be used when content can not be handled by
>   the rendering engine, and should be downloaded instead. This will
>   replace the current handler.

[DownloadListener interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/DownloadListener.html) `onDownloadStart` method:

> Notify the host application that a file should be downloaded