# Download mp4 in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, mp4

I have a `WebView` which goes to a website which has `mp4` files available for download, but when i press the download button nothing happens. Is there any way to be able to download the file through the `WebView`?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview) might help you.good luck.

Comment: Many sites use some javascript instead of a plain vanilla link. Did you activate javascript for the WebView?

Answer (score -1):

there is method of WebView let you Do It :

```
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            downloadMethod(url);
            return true; // false : allow redirect , true : intercept redirect
        }
    });
```

take Care to **return** Boolean .