# Download PDF file in android web view

Tags: android, download, android-webview, jspdf

I am using the jsPDF to convert the html to pdf file. In websites it works fine but in android `webview` when clicking a button it only reloads the page. I searched all but nothing works fine.

I added the below code in main activity:

`mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});`

I am new to android.
Please help me to find it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added manifest permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` ?

Comment: Yes i give the permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Add code part also, so one can give better solution.

Comment: I hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview will help you out.

Comment: I referred that also... but it gives a logcat error as no activity is present

Comment: For that `Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` will be helpful.

Comment: After updating code, same  error found that  `PID: 13414 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle  Intent`

Comment: Did you register your activity in Manifest.xml?

Comment: Sorry... can u please explain it... i use only the web view.. how can i register the activity... the Main activity is registered in the manifest file.  I included the action in main activity intent `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

Comment: Yaa, I was asking for that same.

Comment: Is your problem resolved?