# React-Native: Downloading and uploading files from android webview

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I am using the React-Native webview bridge module because I need its functions and now I am trying to make work the downloading and uploading files. For downloading I was sending a message with the url of the file and then using the Linking package to download in browser, unfortunately I was getting that the download is unsuccessful. Is there a way how I can manage both to work on this module?

Comment: What about use base64 to convert the file to a string an upload/download that string?

Comment: I did managed to make the download like this but not the upload.

Comment: I'm doing this in a React Native app, just make sure you are sending a json message properly formatted and also the headers of the request.

Comment: Do you have a public repo to see your example? Also how did you trigger the filemanager?

Comment: No, but I can paste the code as a response. Regarding to the filemanager, I'm just sending pictures, so is the image picker the one that takes care of that.

Comment: But like this I can still not trigger the button in the webview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had to face the same problem for Android (although only for file uploads). You can see my implementation here: https://github.com/martinarroyo/react-native-webview-file-upload/

Maybe if you extend that code to include something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069265/2628463) you can include file downloading.

Comment: I need somehow to use it together with the webview bridge module because I need its functions. Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean [this package](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge/)? I guess the only thing you have to do is to integrate [this functionality](https://github.com/martinarroyo/react-native-webview-file-upload/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/webviewfileuploadandroid/androidWebView/AndroidWebViewManager.java#L32) into the rn-webview-bridge's `AndroidWebViewManager`. Also you will have to look into the `AndroidWebViewPackager` to handle the activity reference, and edit the JavaScript file to include the required prop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch(
            _apiRoot+url+'?_format=json&access_token='+this.getAccessToken(),
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body:JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                success(response.data);
            })
            .catch((errorData) => {
                error(errorData);
            });

//Where data is an object like

let data = {
  images:[responseDataFromImagePicker.data,responseDataFromImagePicker.data]
}
//the picker returns the image encoded in base64
```