# Webview download file

Tags: android, webview, download

I am opening a webpage inside android webview. After filling the information on the webpage there is a button to download file. But the file is not downloading. I have a confusion regarding which url to pass to the download task . Clinking on the button should download a pdf file. But it does not do anything

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setMimeType(mimetype);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");

                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);


            }
        });
```

Comment: have you set correct permissions? Share your manifest file and put logger inside your code and share logs

Comment: have you set correct permissions? Share your manifest file and put logger inside your code and share logs

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

Comment: does it give any error in log? refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview

Comment: Please explain the url that we pass to the download listener, because when we click on a download button inside the opened page that is a different url

Comment: it does not give any error, the download button goes into inactive state after clicking on download

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

});

Comment: I have put log file inside download listener, but it seems it is not going inside