# Android Webview with link new tab

Tags: android, pdf, webview, download

Let's say I have an Android app that uses a webview. Inside that webview I have a link to download a PDF file like so:

```
<a href="LinkToDownloadPDF" target="_blank".../>
```

In a browser (Say Chrome for example), this will either download the file or opens it in a new tab.

**My question is, what will happen once the webview is charged in the Android app? Will it download the file or open the web browser?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will happen when you download from webview without setting the download listener.

If you want to implement the feature of downloading something inside WebView, have a look at this question: [Download File inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

Comment: That's great. I guess don't have to worry about the target="_blank" then. Thank you

Comment: You're Welcome :)