# Choose file inside webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I create code webview in Android Studio. When try to run an application (webview apps) and click a link to download a file nothing happens. what should i do?`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://my-url/");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

`

Comment: I think this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to add these lines it may work

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Other webview options
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);  
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

these lines may help you

Answer (score 0):

hope so this will be helpful for you

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;

public class BrowserScreen extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String url = "url";


    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initFields();
        setListeners();


    }




    public void initFields() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    }


    public void setListeners() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                webView.loadUrl("http://my-url/");

                view.clearHistory();
            }


        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {


            }

            //The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }


        });



            webView.loadUrl(url);


        final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
                = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (webView.canGoBack() == true) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"Button3\").innerHTML = \"bye\";");
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void openAndroidDialog() {
            AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                    = new AlertDialog.Builder(BrowserScreen.this);
            myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
            myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
            myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
            myDialog.show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
}
```