# How can I download documents or files in webview

Tags: android

Here is the new updated code but still give me the error "Unauthorized.You do not have permission for this action" I want to know why this error thanks. I have implemented the recommended answers still didnt work.

```html
public class TipsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_REQ = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    private static boolean verifyPermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int WritePermision = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (WritePermision != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_REQ,
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION
            );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView7);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                        long contentLength) {
                if (verifyPermissions(TipsActivity.this)) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                            mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
//prompt user for permission
                }

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    }
```

Here is the new updated code but still give me the error "Unauthorized.You do not have permission for this action" I want to know why this error thanks. I have implemented the recommended answers still didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE!** add permission of writing external storage in manifest and also take runtime permission from user for post lolipop api devices

for runtime persmission check this [Document Link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)

in your activity declare this first as field (GLOBAL VARIABLE)

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_REQ = {
           Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
private static boolean verifyPermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int WritePermision = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (WritePermision != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_REQ,
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION
            );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Use the above method in your download manager somewhat like this**

```
 mwebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
       {

      @Override  
       public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
            long contentLength) {
if(verifyPermissions(yourActivity.this)){
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                        url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
//prompt user for permission
}

    }});
```

for more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

Comment: It gave me an error saying "You do not have permission for this action" and in my android manifest file I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: you should use runtime permission check its required for post lollipop Api . pre lollipop api never required permission for user sensitive operations like read or write external storage. but now it has to be coded check this

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: how can I implemented this to my code im new to this

Comment: @user333210 check the edited answer

Comment: Here what I have :

Comment: I implement my code to yours and still give the error.

Comment: check the edited code

Comment: @user333210 Please do not edit answers to change their code. Edit your question if you have new code to share.

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: It gave me an error saying "You do not have permission for this action" and in my android manifest file I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Which api level are you testing at?

Comment: android version is Oreo

Comment: Api level 23 and above you need to ask for permission at run time

Comment: How can I implement it to my code , im new to this

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: If you go to your phone settings and goto applications and then select you application,in the permissions sections you can see if they are enabled or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission

Comment: Still does not work