# How to use file webview and be able to download files

Tags: html, android-studio

Just to say in case it's not obvious I am extremely new to using android studio and the only language I know is HTML. So I set up a HTML app but when I put in
`<a href="file/apk.apk" download>Install</a>` it does not download. I have storage permissions so I must be missing something. ***With explanations please dumb it down as much as possible***

Comment: It looks like this has been asked a few times ([in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388822/how-can-i-download-documents-or-files-in-webview) and [also this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)), but it boils down to having storage writing permissions and setting `setDownloadListener` on your webview to handle the file download.

Comment: @EssXTee Followed it, but when I hit download it just crashes Edit:tried it with a text file but it just opens it (not what I want) but I'll figure it out thank you for the sources