# In App Downloading of an Excel File Not Working

Tags: android, ios, kotlin

First of all, let me emphasize that we are not looking for a specific code snippets for a solution. We believe that this problem of ours started with some design flaws. So we are looking for a general direction with which we can start looking for specific methods to solve this issue.

We have an app that has an notice board where admins and users can create threads.

However, we made a thread where people can download our excel template. We posted our link to this excel file like so:

(I apologize for non-English thread as we are located in Korea)

[image: This is the thread in question]

So in this thread page, the image in the middle is the link.

When you tap(click) on this image, a more detailed download page shows up.

[image: download page]

When you press the download button, nothing happens. It is supposed to automatically lead to downloading process but it does not.

I suspect that the problem resides in our application structure where whatever a user does in the thread stays in the webview and webview only. Is there any way to make this download take place? The only workaround we found is to press and hold the link button until some options show up and press "open in the browser". However, this is quite inconvenient for normal users and we need to fix this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: While it sounds like you have a native app wrapping a webview, you should check how your code is/isn't downloading. No one except you (or your mobile developers) can know your code. See: [Download file inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10069050/295004)